# Can one earn money from Lifetime Learning Credit if one does not pay income tax?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, tuition

I am an independent student with no taxable income. When I file taxes, I do not need to pay any income tax and get no refund. Some students told me that I can get up to 20% of my tuition fees refunded if I file for Lifetime Learning Credit when filing my taxes. Can I receive such money or does that only apply to people who paid taxes? Is this really just a discount on the amount one pays in taxes to the IRS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were told wrong.

Lifetime Learning Credit is **not** a refundable credit. I.e.: it reduces your tax liability, but you cannot get refund if it exceeds your tax liability. See [the IRS pub 970](http://www.irs.gov/publications/p970/ch03.html) for more information:

> A tax credit reduces the amount of income tax you may have to pay.
>   Unlike a deduction, which reduces the amount of income subject to tax,
>   a credit directly reduces the tax itself. **The lifetime learning credit
>   is a nonrefundable credit. This means that it can reduce your tax to
>   zero, but if the credit is more than your tax the excess will not be
>   refunded to you.**

You may be able to qualify for a different benefit: the American Opportunity credit. This one is (partially) refundable. See [here](http://www.irs.gov/publications/p970/ch02.html) for details. [This credit is available until 2017](http://www.irs.gov/uac/American-Opportunity-Tax-Credit).

Comment: [This article you link](http://www.irs.gov/publications/p970/ch02.html) says "there are two tax credits available to help you offset the costs of higher education by reducing the amount of your income tax". Does that also mean no money would be given, as I do not need to pay any income tax?

Comment: @Village as I said - one (the one you asked about) is non-refundable and if you don't pay any taxes it doesn't provide you any benefit. The other one is partially refundable but harder to qualify for. Check the details in the link. You cannot claim both, you have to chose which one you want to claim, and if you qualify for the American Opportunity - you should claim it first.

Comment: So the American Opportunity credit actually is refunding the tuition, not the taxes?

Comment: @Village no, it is not refunding tuition. It is a tax credit, your university has nothing to do with it. You get a refund form the IRS.

Comment: So, it is possible to get a refund on $0 paid? I can pay $0 in taxes over the year, and get some money given to me by the IRS because I paid tuition?

Comment: *IF* you can qualify for that specific program, yes.

Comment: @Village yes. That's the meaning of "refundable credit". There are several credits in the US tax code that are refundable. American Opportunity is one of them.